# RestRequest.AddFileBytes posting corrupted files

Tags: restsharp

I'm trying to POST image files to a service using RestRequest.AddFileBytes, however when I do this, the file seems to be corrupted.  When I download it back, the filesize is ever so slightly off, and depending on the file type, it may appear to have the wrong extension or be uninterpretable (presumably b/c the header is messed up)

When I attempt to do the same thing with Postman it file is OK, so it would seem to be something with the way I'm posting the file.  Please advise!

```
private static bool AddPageBytes(string user, string password, string documentId, string fileName, string contentType, byte[] bytes)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"AddPageBytes documentId:{documentId}  fileName:{fileName} contentType:{contentType} bytes:{bytes.Length}");
            var client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
            var request = new RestRequest("v1/document/{id}/page", Method.POST);

            request.AddUrlSegment("id", documentId);

            request.AddHeader("X-IntegrationServer-Username", user);
            request.AddHeader("X-IntegrationServer-Password", password);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

            request.AddHeader("X-IntegrationServer-FileSize", bytes.Length.ToString());

            request.AddHeader("X-IntegrationServer-Resource-Name", fileName);
            request.AddFileBytes(fileName, bytes, fileName, contentType);


            var response = client.Execute(request);

            return response.IsSuccessful;

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Woudln't you know it, like clockwork I banged my head for the better part of 2 days then posted this question and almost immediately figured out how to make it work.  I wouldn't stay that I know why one is right and one is only *mostly* right (which is obviously not good enough) but

I just had to change

```
request.AddFileBytes(fileName, bytes, fileName, contentType);
```

to

```
request.AddParameter(contentType, bytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: This post quite literally saved my sanity right now. Uploading to AWS/S3, I could not get `AddFile` or `AddFileBytes` to result in anything but garbage. Your solution got me on the right track, everything is a-okay now :)

Comment: I'm glad to know one of my stackoverflow monologues helped someone for once :)

Comment: OMG, Thank you so much. I was also trying to use AddFileBytes for over a day with no luck. Your solution worked for me. I feel like there is a bug with that method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have been having a rough run at work lately, this helped :)

Comment: Thank you I was trying AddFile and it wouldnt work. Saved me ton.